# System.Web.HttpException Could not load type '[namespace].???'

Tags: asp.net, web, types

This started as Could not load type 'Global' error. After I tried a few things and getting no where I deleted the Global.asax file and now the error is Could not load type '[namespace].???'

Where ??? is the class name of every page I try to load

The web site (when executed within VS2008, local dev computer) works fine but once published (with no errors) and deployed to the server gives me Could not load type '[namespace].???' error

I did install elmah and I was able to get more details for this "generic" Could not load type '[namespace].???' error

elmah reports a HTTP error 500 :

System.Web.HttpException Could not load type '[namespace].???' -> 
System.Web.HttpParseException: Could not load type '[namespace].???'

Any ideas?

I have checked the "basics"

- References
- Doing a clean and a build
- Checking the Inherits attr in the HTML against the code behind

UPDATE #1

I did deploy the site to a different DEV computer (configured IIS, virtual folder, etc.) and it works. When I use the same published code on the server, get the generic Could not load type '[namespace].???' error

UPDATE #2

I created a test web app. One form (Default.aspx) with a button. The click event does a Response.Write("Hello World"); I moved this app to the server and guess what, I get the Could not load type TestSite._Default

UPDATE #3

According to the fusion log viewer, these two websites are attempting to load CppCodeProvider and VJSharpCodeProvider, but I have no references to any of these. After a Google search, I found this [post](http://dotnetslackers.com/CSharp/re-68323_The_CodeDom_provider_type_Microsoft_VJSharp_VJSharpCodeProvider_could_not_be_located.aspx)

I checked and I have no references to JAVA files. Still don't know what the problem is

Comment: I've got similar problem. In my case, one of the visual studio dll got corrupted somehow. Re-installing visual studio worked for me.

Comment: You Should check the .Net Framework version in the Property of the Project.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, sometimes we get this error when the disk is full.

Comment: Yes I would look into this and/or permissions on the server that is throwing the error. Sounds like the .NET runtime is not loading the assemblies. 
Maybe try giving the user specified in the IIS App pool full rights (or alternatively temporarily change the user to an admin account) - or as Anar suggests check that the drive with Windows installed has sufficient free disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the project file is uploaded to the build server along with the added files.  VS will add lines to this file that points to the new files location.

```
    <Content Include="xxx.aspx" />  

    <Compile Include="xxx.aspx.cs">
     <DependentUpon>xxx.aspx</DependentUpon>
     <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
```

Without the updated project file it will not find the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Really weird, maybe you should try to test it in a different server, this happens for example when you are using in you dev environment some namespaces from .NET 4.5 and you haven't installed the same framework in your server, so maybe the error is related to this behavior, if you are not using any third dll in your web application outside Microsoft's framework, so should try to reinstall the framework, I don't think the problem is related to visual studio.